# fancybox 2.0.6 close button custom action

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

i'm trying to plugin custom action to fancy close button, but nothing is happening, why is that ??

my code

```
$(".fancybox-close").click(function(){
    $("#main-menu-nav a").removeClass("active");
    $("footer").toggleClass("down", 400);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Fancybox v1` provides API with a `onClosed` method that's called when Fancybox closes.
`Fancybox v2` provides API with a `afterClose` method that's called when Fancybox closes.

The [**Tips & Tricks**](http://fancybox.net/blog) page has the method to use this public callback as seen below:

```
$("#tip5").fancybox({
    'scrolling'     : 'no',
    'titleShow'     : false,
    'afterClose'        : function() {
       $("#main-menu-nav a").removeClass("active");
       $("footer").toggleClass("down", 400);
    }
});
```

Using this method to call your custom actions will ensure they are invoked when the overlay is clicked to close Fancybox, since the button itself isn't clicked.

**Status Update:** Per Simon's Answer on this page, note his point that you may have an issue with the `switch parameter` for the `.toggleClass();` method since the value of `400` may not do what your expecting unless (as the comment states), your using **jQuery UI**.

Comment: in facybox 2 onClosed changed to afterClose, works fine thx guys

Comment: **+1** Thanks for letting me know about the different API's available. I've changed your Question's tag to reflect `fancybox-2` instead. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Fancybox has a callback onClose you can define in its parameters

please try to use:

```
$("#TARGET_ELEMENT").fancybox({
 'OTHER_PARAM':'OTHER_PARAM_VALUE',
 'onClosed': function() {
   alert("FIRED_ON_CLOSE");
  }
 });
```

Happy coding!

Comment: **+1** for being the first to respond with correct answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

`$("footer").toggleClass("down", 400);` is invalid jQuery code, toggleClass's second parameter must be a boolean http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/.

Comment: **+1** for correct Answer that this is invalid jQuery if jQuery UI is not used. That said, **+1** for message comment shining light that the duration value is recognized only if *jQuery UI* is used. Case in point: jQuery `.load();` has two method too! Depending on parameters it can become a ***AJAX method***. Cheers!